# Gatsby: How to change a node style if <Link /> is active?

Tags: reactjs, onclick, toggle, gatsby

folks! I want to change the style of the inner  inside  if my gatsby Link is active.  I want hide/show submenu by `display: none`. But have no idea how to pass this parameter from Link to somewhere else. Any thoughts? Many thanks

I tried to get or pass the state like on this page [Reach Link](https://reach.tech/router/api/Link), but also no luck

```
return (
  <li key={`sidebar-id${i}`}>
    <Link to={item.path} activeStyle={{ color: "red" }} partiallyActive={true}>
      {item.name}
    </Link>
    <ul className={`${styles.menu__secondLevel} small-body-text`} style={ifLinkisActive}>
      {subItems}
    </ul>
  </li>
);
```

Here is the whole code for Sidebar items:

```
const SidebarItems = routes.map((item, i) => {
  // If Sidebar has sub items
  if (item.items) {
    // Loop trough sub items
    const subItems = item.items.map((subItem, j) => {
      return (
        <li key={`sidebar-id${j}`}>
          <Link to={subItem.path}>{subItem.name}</Link>
        </li>
      );
    });
    // Main menu with "subItems" variable
    return (
      <li key={`sidebar-id${i}`}>
        <Link
          to={item.path}
          activeStyle={{ color: "red" }}
          partiallyActive={true}
        >
          {item.name}
        </Link>
        <ul className={`${styles.menu__secondLevel} small-body-text`}>
          {subItems}
        </ul>
      </li>
    );
    // If doesn't have
  } else {
    return (
      <li key={`sidebar-id${i}`}>
        <Link to={item.path} activeStyle={{ color: "red" }}>
          {item.name}
        </Link>
      </li>
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can solve this with css. Gatsby's `Link` has a `activeClassName` prop that'll attach a class to active link. You can use css `+` selector to style the sibling `ul`.

```css
a.active {
  color: red;
}

.active + .submenu {
  display: block;
}

.submenu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a class="active" href="#">Active</a>
<ul class="submenu">
  <li>Submenu</li>
</ul>
```

Here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/ypqxpl40vj) with reach-router Link, but customized a bit to match Gatsby Link's props.

Comment: Thank you, Darek for the help. I thought about that and it's a good decision :-) But I wanted to keep <a/> inside <li/> for accessibility and also wandered might be I'm doing something wrong and there is another way :-)

Comment: @PavelLaptev I was just mimicking your structure -- you have `<Link>` &  `<ul>` next to eachother inside a `<li>`. Perhaps I misunderstood your question, could you clarify a bit more?

Comment: It's me, Darek. I was stupid :-) Didn't notice that sorry. And thank you again

Comment: @pavelLaptev hahah no worries, glad it helped! I'm sure there's a more react-y way to handle this (thats not involve css). If I come up with something, I'll add to the answer.

Comment: that's nice! I was going to to dig into redux :)